# How to check if first column's string of file1 exist in the file2?

Tags: sed, files, grep, string, search

I have two files, `file1.txt` contains strings separated by commas:

```
1.1.1.1,string1,comment1
7.7.7.7,string3,comment3
2.2.2.2,string2,comment2
88.88.88.88,string4,comment4
999.999,999,999,string5,comment5
```

The second file, `file2.txt`, contains strings that can appear in the first column of `file1.txt`. I need to remove the whole row in `file1.txt` if its first column's string appears in `file2.txt`. Please note that I do not want to change th original file, but I want to put the output in a new file.

Comment: If you don't need to restrict the match to the first column of `file1.txt` specifically, then probably something like `grep -vFf file2.txt file1.txt > newfile` should do

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
grep -vffile2 file1
```

> ```
> -f FILE: Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
> -v:      Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
#!/bin/bash 
cat file2.txt | while IFS=, read line; do

sed -i "/$(grep $line file1.txt)/d" file1.txt

done
```

Be aware that `sed -i` will make direct changes to file1.txt, but you can change the command to `sed -i.ibk` in order to save a backup copy of the original file.

For example

```
$cat file2.txt 
1.1.1.1
7.7.7.7

$cat file1.txt 
1.1.1.1,string1,comment1
7.7.7.7,string3,comment3
2.2.2.2,string2,comment2
88.88.88.88,string4,comment4
999.999,999,999,string5,comment5

output 
2.2.2.2,string2,comment2
88.88.88.88,string4,comment4
999.999,999,999,string5,comment5
```

Comment: In order to make sure the result is correct, `sed` can be used on its own without the `i` so that the changes are only sent to `stdout`.